How to type math symbols in text mode?
I am using LaTeX to write a document. I want to explain the LaTeX codes I am using to the reader of this document. So I would like to type the dollar sign, subscription sign, and curly bracket in the text mode. But it does not work. If I shift to math mode, then the reader cannot really "see" them. How shall I fix this problem? (Sorry for possible confusion, I don't know how to explain my problem clearly.)

Looking at a basic guide on LaTeX might reveal useful. The command \verb is what you're looking for.
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

You get $M \otimes_{R} N$ by typing \verb|$M \otimes_{R} N$|.

\end{document}



You have to escape those characters:
\documentclass{report}

\begin{document}
  To write maths, use "\$" on both side of the equation.
  
  Underscripts are given with an underscore "\_" (or \_\{<superscript>\})
\end{document}



Probably "(or _{})" ... (not superscript) :-)

$ _ ^ %, etc. are the primitive/pre-defined symbols in TeX, if you want to print those symbols, then you can go with verbatim environment, and the MWE is:
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{verbatim}
$ _ ^ %
\end{verbatim}

\end{document}

